# Sprite alignment in a Sprite Packing C application

Tags: c, animation, sprite, bmp, sprite-sheet

I am creating the "perfect" sprite packer. This is a sprite packer that makes sure the output sprite is compatible with most if not all game engines and animation software. It is a program that merges images into a horizontal sprite sheet.

1. It converts (if needed) the source frames to BMP in memory
2. It considers the top-left pixel fully transparent for the entire image (can be configured)
3. It parses the frames each individually to find the real coordinates rect (where the actual frame starts, ends, its width and height (sometimes images may have a lot of extra transparent pixels).
4. It determines the frame box, which have the width and height of the frame with the largest width/height so that it is long enough to contain every frame. (For extra compatibility, every frame must have the same dimensions).
5. Creates output sprite with width of nFrames * wFrameBox

The problem is - anchor alignment. Currently, it tries to align each frame so that its center is on the frame box center.

```
if((wBox / 2) > (frame->realCoordinates.w / 2))
{
    xpos = xBoxOffset + ((wBox / 2) - (frame->realCoordinates.w / 2));
}
else
{
    xpos = xBoxOffset + ((frame->realCoordinates.w / 2) - (wBox / 2));
}
```

When animated, it looks better with it, but there is still this inconsistent horizontal frame position so that a walking animation looks like walking and shaking.
I also tried the following:
store the real x pixel position of the widest frame and use it as a reference point:
`xpos = xBoxOffset + (frame->realCoordinates.x - xRef);`
It also gives a little better results, showing that this is still not the correct algorithm.
Honestly, I don't know what am I doing.

What will be the correct way to align sprite frames (obtain the appropriate x position for drawing the next frame) given that the output sprite sheet have width of the number of frames multiplied by the width of the widest frame?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you first calculate the center then calculate the size of the required bounding box. That is why your image 'shakes' because in each image that center is different to the original center.

You should use the center of the original bounding box as your origin, then find out the size of each sprite, keeping track of the leftmost, rightmost, topmost and bottommost non transparent pixels. That would give you the bounding box you need to use to avoid the shaking.

The problem is that you will find that most sprites are already done that way, so the original bounding box is actually defined as to the minimum space to paint the whole sprite's sequence covering these non transparent pixels.

The only way to remove unused sprite space is to store the first sprite complete, and then the origin and dimensions of each other sprite, like is done in animated GIF and APNG ( Animated PNG -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG )

Comment: Thank you. I think my program should output A. The sprite B. Each frame cropped of unneeded pixels detected as transparent, C. A binary file with the already-determined actual width and height and a GIF (to make gif I should probably convert frames to png and cut the transparent pixels with ImageMagick or something). Do you think it worths sharing and open sourcing it?

Comment: In the app, each frame is associated with its leftmost, rightmost (which essentially is leftmost (x) + width), topmost and bottommost (topmost (y) + height) and the transparent color detected. The center of the bounding box `wBox / 2` is constant but I found out that you are right and the calculations from the question (minus the frame offset) actually produce different results for every frame. The motivation behind this was to shift position so that bounding box center and frame center matches, thought this would align them properly

Comment: Do you mean that I should not allocate a fixed (sufficient minimum) width for every frame? If I pack them tight I don't think it will work everywhere, including in my game engine.

Comment: I mean I have each frame's x,y,w,h but I don't get you what should I do with them

Comment: I would not recommend you the use of GIF because -as you said- it lacks transparency and supports a maximum of 256 colours.  I think that APNG is better for your purpose. The format is just a normal PNG with the firs frame at full size, and then other chunks with the frames to change, each giving location and dimension of the frame, as well as other stuff like timing. The only limitation is that each frame has to fit inside of the initial  PNG image. Its a great format because a PNG reader will play the sprite (eg a browser) and is compressed.

Comment: Read the info in the link I wrote in my answer and you will know what to do with your x,y,w,h. There is an open source library called libpng-apng which provides support to read/write these APNG files. https://github.com/rickytan/libpng-apng.

Comment: I can't use APNG, because it is not supported everywhere, including in the engine I use for my project, which /required/ me to create this tool. In any other situation, I'd gladly use APNG.

Comment: My suggestion to use APNG is because is always good to use an standard format rather than your own format, which is what I think you are doing. Contrary to what you think, APNG is widely supported. Click in here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APNG with any browser and you will see a bouncing ball in the right hand side. That is an APNG.

Comment: Even Apple uses APNG for the animated stickers in iMessage. Go https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/extensions/messaging/#stickers and scroll to 'Sticker Formats'.

Comment: But again, it was just a suggestion. I am just trying to show that someone else walked your steps before. At least you know now how to fix your problem. :-)

Comment: It is generally a piece of good advice towards the majority, but the platform I use hasn't been updated enough to support APNG. It is old too.

Comment: What I did is to give an option to use "natural alignment", which is to not deteriorate the animation with alignment algorithms, but crop a fixed area (of the largest frame) of each frame and therefore preserve the natural alignment. In my case, I have a number of frames captured with AnimGet and it works out well because each frame is big enough. I still can't figure out why centering did not work though, but the program I am writing may give me a clue as I program it and use it.

Comment: Well, the main goal has been achieved and whoever reach here will know about APNG. ;-) all the best with your work!